# onReceive not called when removing Widgets on Lock Screen - Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-4.2-jelly-bean, lockscreen

I want to enable my widget on the lock screen on Jelly Bean (Nexus 7, Android 4.2.1)

My problem is that `onReceive()` is never called when you remove a widget from the lock screen, creating as many ghost widgets as you add/remove it.

It works ok in home screen (you remove a widget, `onReceive()` is called, then `onDelete()` and if it is the last widget `onDisable()`), but is not working on lock screen.

On the lock screen `onReceive()` is called for `APPWIDGET_ENABLED`, `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and `APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS` and that's it.

To place a widget in the lock screen, you just need to add `android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"` to your widget and test it on lock screen

Comment: Reported as a bug in Android
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40993&thanks=40993&ts=1354749219

Comment: Same experience here. Thanks for filing the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same experience with my Jelly Bean lock screen widget. onReceive(), onDelete() and onDIsable() are never called and the widget keeps updating even after you removed it from the lock screen. Same behavior on both my Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1) and Nexus 7 (4.2.1).
The ghost widgets disappear after a reboot.

Maybe something to do with the behavior of the built-in lock screen widgets. The clock reappears after you delete it.

Hope this get clarified in the docs some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

"An AppWidgetProvider needs to be exported, so that the core OS process that coordinates app widgets (between hosts and providers) can talk to it. Hence, `android:exported="false"` is inapropos.
To be honest, I would have expected nothing to work with the provider, rather than only some events."

CommonsWare

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719694/4683601

```
        <receiver 
            android:name=".AppWidgetBarProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_bar_info" />
        </receiver>
```