# WidgetProvider onDisable, onDeleted not called

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

In my widget I started Timer. It's work fine, everything is ok. But if I remove widget from home screen, onDisable or onDeleted is not called.

I try with onReceive but my Log.i() give my only onUpdate.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    super.onReceive(context, intent);       
    Log.i("onReceive", intent.getAction());
}

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
{       
        timer = new Timer();         
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TasksView(context, appWidgetManager), 100, 5000);
        [...]
}
```

Additional, I have:

```
@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) 
{       
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    Log.i("MyTag", "onDeleted");                
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) 
{
    super.onDisabled(context);
    Log.i("MyTag", "onDisabled");                 
}
```

and:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" /> 
            <action android:name="com.opennet.supportportal.UPDATE_LIST_WARN" />
```

So, how I can stop my timer? Why onDisable or onDeleted is not called?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in android 1.5 that the onDeleted method is not called. The code below placed in the onRecive fixes the problem.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{        
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
}
```

[More info here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:exported="true"` in your Provider Manifest declaration.

[onDelete() method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719694/4683601)